# JavaScript search script not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: php, javascript

I've the following search script but it doesn't seem to be working at all in IE. It always comes back with the "Sorry, we couldn't find anyone using that search criteria..." error.

The code is as follows:

```
<?

$getmystatus = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM members WHERE ID = '$session_memberid'");
while($getmys = mysql_fetch_array($getmystatus))
{
$mystatus = $getmys['status'];
}


?>

<script language=javascript>

function search() {

var snum = 0;

var name = $("#search_name").val();
var city = $("#search_city").val();
var country = $("#search_country").val();
var jobtitle = $("#search_jobtitle").val();
var company = $("#search_company").val();
var minage = $("#search_minage").val();
var maxage = $("#search_maxage").val();
var industry = $("#search_industry").val();
var male = $('#search_male').is(':checked'); 
var female = $('#search_female').is(':checked');
var token = $("#mtoken").val();

if(!city) { city = ''; } else {}
if(!country) { country = ''; } else {}
if(!jobtitle) { jobtitle = ''; } else {}
if(!company) { company = ''; } else {}
if(!minage) { minage = '0'; } else {}
if(!maxage) { maxage = '0'; } else {}
if(!industry) { industry = ''; } else {}


if ( name != '' ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( city != '' ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( country != '' ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( jobtitle != '' ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( company != '' ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( minage != '0' ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( maxage != '0' ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( industry != '' ) { snum = snum+1; }

if ( male == true ) { snum = snum+1; }
if ( female == true ) { snum = snum+1; }

if ( snum < 1 ) {

$('#sverif').html('<font color=red>Select al least 1 type</font>');

} else {

$('#searchres_nresults').hide().html("<table border='0'><tr><td><img width=60 src='/images/loading.gif'></td><td>Searching ..</td></tr></table> ").fadeIn();
$('#sverif').html('');

var dataString = "token="+token+"&name="+name+"&city="+city+"&country="+country+"&jobtitle="+jobtitle+"&company="+company+"&minage="+minage+"&maxage="+maxage+"&industry="+industry+"&male="+male+"&female="+female;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajsearch.php",
            async: true,
            data: dataString, 
            success: function(data) {

                $("#searchres_results").html(data);
                $("#searchres_results").css("display","block");
                var snresnum = $("#searchresults_number").html();
                if ( snresnum == '0' ) {

                    $("#searchres_nresults").delay(3000).html("<div class=t23>Sorry, we couldn't find anyone using that search criteria...</div>");

                } else {

                    $("#searchres_nresults").delay(3000).html("<div class=t23>Great news, we've found "+snresnum+" people...</div>");

                }

            }

        });


}
</script>
```

The HTML form is as expected so I won't include it apart from the last submit button in case that helps:

```
<div class="profilebutton" onclick="search();">Search</div>
<div class="boxleft" id='searchres_results' style='display:none;'>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note, you can leave out all the `else {}` statements - if you are not using the else block - you don't have to explicitly define it.

Comment: I don't see any code that ever sets the value of `$("#searchresults_number")`...

Comment: @jbabey it is possibly in the `data` variable, which is the response returned from the server. Although this is not very clean. It would not hurt to see the actual html.

Comment: Thanks! It's included in ajsearch.php - I didn't include that as it's rather a long document and I don't think it's the document causing the issue but I could be wrong :/

Comment: Just a thought... the HTML form has no `<form>` open or closing with an action attached. That wouldn't have any affect would it?

Comment: @EdzJohnson No, that shouldn't have any **effect** on it as long as the HTML can be correctly parsed. You don't need an actual `form` to manipulate HTML.

Comment: Open your developer console (press F12 in IE9+ and every other modern browser), and inspect the contents of HTTP packets sent and received. It is hard to debug asynchronous requests without reading packet content.

Comment: Also I see you're saying it's "not working in Internet Explorer." Is the implication here that it *does* work in other browsers and this is an IE-only problem?

Comment: @NullUserException -yup working everywhere apart from IE.

Answer (score 0):

For `Sorry, we couldn't find anyone using that search criteria...` to be outputted you need to reach that line of code. That means that `snresnum == '0'` is `true`.

This is because you set:

```
var snresnum = $("#searchresults_number").html();
```

And `$("#searchresults_number").html()` is `'0'`.

Be sure the value inside the element with the `id="searchresults_number"` is generated correctly in `ajsearch.php`. It is always `0` now.